# Reverse part of an array using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use array slicing to reverse part of a [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) array. If my array is, for example,

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

then I can get a slice b

```
b = a[::-1]
```

Which is a view on the original array. What I would like is a view that is partially reversed, for example

```
1,4,3,2,5,6
```

I have encountered performance problems with NumPy if you don't play along exactly with how it is designed, so I would like to avoid "fancy" indexing if it is possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't like the off by one indices

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> a[1:4] = a[1:4][::-1]
>>> a
array([1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Is this double slicing `a[1:4][::-1]` the proper pythonic way, or is there a solution using a single slice? Couldn't this be done simpler via `a[3:0:-1]`?

Comment: @Walter, yes that's what John Zwinck's answer does, but it is not as clear to the reader which elements are being selected.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> a[1:4] = a[3:0:-1]
>>> a
array([1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [permutation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) (that's the numpiest way to partially reverse an array).

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
new_order_for_index = [1,4,3,2,5,6] # Careful: index from 1 to n !

# Permutation matrix
m = np.zeros( (len(a),len(a)) )
for index , new_index  in enumerate(new_order_for_index ):
    m[index ,new_index -1] = 1

print np.dot(m,a)
# np.array([1,4,3,2,5,6])
```

Comment: You can't throw code in a for loop and call it the numpiest.