# Reverse a slice of an array in-place

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, reverse, in-place

What is the best (fastest/most pythonic) way to reverse a **part** of an array **in-place**?

E.g.,

```
def reverse_loop(l,a,b):
    while a < b:
        l[a],l[b] = l[b],l[a]
        a += 1
        b -= 1
```

now after

```
l = list(range(10))
reverse_loop(l,2,6)
```

`l` is `[0, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 9]` as desired.

Alas, looping in Python is inefficient, so a better way is needed, [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3705670/850781),

```
def reverse_slice(l,a,b):
    l[a:b+1] = l[b:a-1:-1]
```

and `reverse_slice(l,2,6)` restores `l` to its original value.

Alas, this does not work for the border cases: `reverse_slice(l,0,6)`
truncates `l` to `[7, 8, 9]` because `l[a:-1:-1]` should be `l[a::-1]`.

So, what is The Right Way?

Comment: `l[0:6] = l[0:6][::-1]` should work. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469012/reverse-part-of-an-array-using-numpy)

Comment: @student It seems to me that that question is about `numpy` arrays, whereas this is about Python `lists`.

Comment: @gmds do you mean it does not work for array other than numpy?

Comment: @student There are subtle differences. In particular, slicing will work the same way, but the `reversed` method will not.

Comment: @gmds I think the **accepted** answer in the link above returns the expected result. `a[1:4] = a[1:4][::-1]` is same as `l[a:b] = l[a:b][::-1]`

Comment: @student It does indeed, but the semantics of arrays and `lists` are slightly different, as evinced in `reversed` working in one case but not the other. That, to me, distinguishes the two questions sufficiently (see [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)); the accepted answer working in both cases seems to be neither here nor there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
def reverse_slice(l, a, b):
    l[a:b] = l[a:b][::-1]

l = list(range(10))
reverse_slice(l, 0, 6)  # excludes l[6]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

An alternative with the inbuilt function `reversed`:

```
def reverse_func(l, a, b):
    l[a:b] = reversed(l[a:b])
```

In my tests, slicing is faster than using `reversed` by a factor of 1.2x-1.5x.

Answer (score 0):

`[6::-1]` can be written as `[6:None:-1]`:

```
def reverse_slice(l,a,b):
    a1 = None if a==0 else a-1
    l[a:b+1] = l[b:a1:-1]

In [164]: y=x.copy(); reverse_slice(y,1,6);y                                    
Out[164]: [0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9]
In [165]: y=x.copy(); reverse_slice(y,0,6);y                                    
Out[165]: [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: is this faster than the repeated slicing?